# Telerik RadGrid causes Value Exception when in edit mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I sure hope someone will be kind enough to help me with this while I have a shred of sanity left :(

I have a radgrid, databound through a LINQ query.  It displays as it should, and I added a details button that works fine.  But when I hit the edit button I get:
"JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Selection out of range
Parameter name: value"

I've pored over the values I'm getting and I don't see a problem, obvious or otherwise. My grid follows (sorry, it's a bit of a mess):

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" 
       DataMember="id" 
        onneeddatasource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" 
            OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid1_UpdateCommand" PageSize="20" 
            onitemcommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand" >
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="status,charity,make,model,year,vin,date,id,salePrice,bid,note" 
            EditMode="EditForms" EnableViewState="True">

<CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>

<RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</RowIndicatorColumn>

<ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</ExpandCollapseColumn>

    <Columns>
    <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="History" Text="History" UniqueName="detailBtn" HeaderText="History" HeaderButtonType="PushButton" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True">
                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
     <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Charity" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column2 column" 
            UniqueName="column3" DataType="System.String" DataField="charity" ReadOnly="True">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
         <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="VIN" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column6 column" 
            UniqueName="column7" DataType="System.String" DataField="vin" >
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
             </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Year" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column2 column" 
            UniqueName="column2" DataType="System.Int32" DataField="year">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Make" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" 
            UniqueName="column" DataType="System.String" DataField="make">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Model" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="column1" DataType="System.String" DataField="model">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>            
             <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Last Update" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="column5" DataType="System.DateTime" DataField="date" ReadOnly="True">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
         <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Min. Bid" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="column8" DataType="System.Decimal" DataField="bid" DataFormatString="{0:C}" >
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn  HeaderText="Sale Price" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="column6" DataType="System.Decimal" DataField="salePrice" DataFormatString="{0:C}" Display="False">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn  HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-Width="140px" FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" 
            UniqueName="unsoldNotesColumn" DataType="System.String" DataField="note" Display="True">
<ItemStyle Width="140px"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 
      <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Latest Status" ItemStyle-Width="240px">


                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>

                        </ItemTemplate>


                        <EditItemTemplate>

                            <telerik:RadComboBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="updateComboBox" DataTextField="Status" 

                                DataValueField="ID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("ID") %>' AutoPostBack="True"
                                >

                            </telerik:RadComboBox>                          

                        </EditItemTemplate>


<ItemStyle Width="240px"></ItemStyle>


                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn FooterText="EditCommand footer" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn"

                        HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" UpdateText="Update">

<HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>

                    </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>



    </Columns>

<EditFormSettings>
<EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn>
</EditFormSettings>
</MasterTableView>

<FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False"></FilterMenu>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

My codebehind, in the event that has a bearing on this is:

```
 private void LoadUnsoldVehicleGrid()
        {


            CAAData2DataContext db = new CAAData2DataContext();


            var ud = db.Updates

             .Where(c => c.Sold.Equals(false))
             .GroupBy(c => c.Vehicle)
            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).First()).ToList();

            var unSoldVehicles = (from u in ud
                                  join v in db.Vehicles on
                                      u.Vehicle equals v.ID
                                  join c in db.Customers on
                                  v.Charity equals c.ID
                                  select new  
                                {
                                    status = u.Status,
                                    make = v.Make,
                                    model = v.Model,
                                    Year = v.Year,
                                    vin = v.VIN_,
                                    charity = c.Name,
                                    date = u.TimeStamp,
                                    id = u.Vehicle,
                                    salePrice = v.SalePrice,
                                    bid = v.MinimumBid,
                                    note=u.Note
                                }).OrderBy(z=>z.charity).ToList();

            RadGrid1.DataSource = unSoldVehicles;



        }
```

What's utterly depressing is that... this WAS working.  I must have changed something inadvertently and by the time I realized it was all... ugh

I'd be deeeeeeply grateful for any insight!

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<telerik:RadComboBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="updateComboBox" DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("ID") %>' AutoPostBack="True">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Most likely, the issue comes from above code block. What you can possibly do is to set `SelectedValue` in the code behind after the `DataBind` method is called on `RadComboBox` control. Hope it helps.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.IsInEditMode) 
    {
        GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
        RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)editItem.FindControl("updateComboBox"); 
        combo.DataBind(); 
        combo.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(editItem.DataItem,"ID").ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: you ARE my savior ;)  I'm using the combobox in edit mode so I wound up with:
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
        {if (e.Item.IsInEditMode) {GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
                RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)editItem.FindControl("updateComboBox");
                combo.DataBind();  combo.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(editItem.DataItem,"ID").ToString(); }}
I can't begin to tell you how grateful I am... I spent all day yesterday on this.  Bizarre that it worked up until... Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm a rank noob here, so I wanted to make sure I tagged you to let you know how deeply grateful I am.  It's astonishing to me that so many people with so much expertise give so generously of their time to help beginners!  

I'm quite new to coding (didn't even start till my fifties) but I do have a deep background in electronics, construction and photography.  Please let me know if I can ever return the favor!  Thank you again, you really made my day!!!

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 No worries at all. Glad to hear that it worked for you. And thanks very much for all the kind words. We are all learning something new every day, because technologies never stop evolving. I am also a beginner in some other areas, and I've got so much help from many others here at SO. For me, the best way to return the favor is by helping the ones who need help with whatever I can. You helping me, I helping you, everyone helping everyone. That's the SO spirit, isn't it :)

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 by the way, here's my email gary[dot]woodkid[at]gmail[dot]com, in case you wish to privately message me or anything. pretty sure we have much to learn from each other. :)

Comment: Thanks Gary!  You saved my bacon and I won't forget it.  Likewise, feel free to catch me at traineronly{at}hotmail<dot>com 

A distinct pleasure meeting you!